# How do I get WSDL file from a running service?

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl

Here's how I start my web service:

```
try
{
    //load the shedluer static constructor
    ServiceHost svh = new ServiceHost(typeof(OrderExecutor));

    var tcpbinding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);

    //remove limits on the max array size
    var httpLocation = "http://" + address + ":1234";

    svh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IOrderExecutor), new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.None), httpLocation);

    ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = svh.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();

    if (smb == null)
        smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();

    smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
    svh.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

    // Add MEX endpoint

    svh.AddServiceEndpoint(
                ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName,
                MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(),
                httpLocation + "/mex"
                );


    svh.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Service mounted at {0}", httpLocation);
    Console.WriteLine("Press Ctrl+c to exit");

    var re = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    re.WaitOne();
    svh.Close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception");
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

The service starts and works ok, Visual studio can connect to it and create a working client.

But, I need a WSDL file to make it inter-operate with PHP.

I've tried

```
http://localhost:1234?wsdl
http://localhost:1234/IOrderExecutor?wsdl
http://localhost:1234/IOrderExecutor.wsdl
```

without any success.

I've also tried

```
svcutil /serviceName:IOrderExecutor order-executor.exe
```

With following result:

```
Warning: Unable to load a service with configName 'IOrderExecutor'. To export
 a service provide both the assembly containing the service type and an executab
le with configuration for this service.
    Details:Either none of the assemblies passed were executables with configura
tion files or none of the configuration files contained services with the config
 name 'IOrderExecutor'.

Warning: No metadata files were generated. No service contracts were exported.
 To export a service, use the /serviceName option. To export data contracts, spe
cify the /dataContractOnly option. This can sometimes occur in certain security
contexts, such as when the assembly is loaded over a UNC network file share. If
this is the case, try copying the assembly into a trusted environment and runnin
g it.
```

How do I get a WSDL file from a running WCF service?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860408/what-is-wsdl-uri-in-wcf

Comment: No result for http://localhost:1234/IOrderExecutor.asmx?WSDL either

Comment: @ArsenZahray than is something wrong. "...asmx?wsdl" sould be if you have deployed properly

Comment: any idea what could be wrong here?

Comment: The wsdl could also be `.svc?wsdl` instead of `.asmx?wsdl` and you should use the service name instead of the interface.

Comment: I've set httpLocation = "http://" + address + ":1234/myservice"; and tried http://localhost:1234/myservice.svc?wsdl and http://localhost:1234/myservice.asmx?wsdl. In both cases I've got 503 (sevice unavaliable). http://localhost:1234/myservice?wsdl is avaliable and returns empty page

Comment: Could you try to only open `http://localhost:1234` and then browse to the service listed there?

Comment: Did you tried to use your mex endpoint? MEX = metadata exchange, I could be wrong, but metadata is passed as WSDL.
http://localhost:1234/mex

Comment: the service does create mex endpoint. At the end I solved the issue by using visual studio to connect to it and create client endpoint. Among the files for the client endpoint, there was the wdsl file.

Answer (score 3):

have you tried 
**localhost:1234/IOrderExecutor/?wsdl**

try this it may works

Comment: Whoa, I've tried /wsdl ?wsdl /mex?wsdl /mex/wsdl /basic?wsdl  /basic/wsdl (i have two endpoints, <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="Mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" /> and <endpoint address="basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="Basic" contract="MyService" />)  and didn't tried /?wsdl.. WTF. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

your answer lies here

```
// Add MEX endpoint

svh.AddServiceEndpoint(
            ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName,
            MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(),
            httpLocation + "/mex"
            );
```

EDIT:
httpLocation + "/mex" is the address where you get the wsdl. also behaviours httpGetEnabled must be true

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

To view wsdl you need to enable MetaData be setting serviceMetadata as below.

```
< serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="**true**" / >
```