# How to use SOAP in Windows 8.1 apps and in Windows Phone 8 apps?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

Is there some methods to create SOAP-requests and to get SOAP-responses in .net-4.5? Which extentions I should to install, if it's necessary?

Comment: Have also a look at Web.API http://www.asp.net/web-api for building RESTful services.

Comment: Afaik, SOAP ASP.NET Webservices have been obsolete since .NET Framework 3.5 :) I advise - move on with the world. WCF is the way to go nowadays (speaking strictly .NET here)

Comment: @Noobgrammer, WCF uses SOAP by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SOAP services via the "Add Service Reference" function in Visual Studio.  Behind the scenes, this will call `svcutil` to convert the `.wsdl` into `.cs` service prototypes.

The .Net Framework includes both WCF, which is the newer and recommended network communication framework, as well as .Net Remoting, which is more compatible with some non-.Net SOAP endpoints.

See

- [Introduction to WCF (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd936243.aspx)
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/950650/138200) to a similar question addressing WCF from a SOAP perspective
- [Walkthrough: Creating and accessing WCF Services (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386386.aspx)
- [what is WSDL URI in WCF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860408/what-is-wsdl-uri-in-wcf)
- [Adding Custom [SOAP] `MessageHeader`s to a WCF Call (MSDN Blog)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2014/02/07/adding-custom-messageheader-and-http-header-to-a-wcf-method-call.aspx)

### Example

For the service located at http://www.webservicex.net/currencyconvertor.asmx?WSDL:

- Generate the client proxy
  `svcutil http://www.webservicex.net/currencyconvertor.asmx?WSDL`
- Rename the config produced
  `move output.config program.exe.config`
- Create a test client:

**Program.cs**:

```
using System;
using www.webservicex.net;

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new CurrencyConvertorSoapClient("CurrencyConvertorSoap");
        var conv = client.ConversionRate(Currency.USD, Currency.EUR);
        Console.WriteLine("Conversion rate from USD to EUR is {0}", conv);
    }
}
```

- Compile
  `csc Program.cs CurrencyConvertor.cs`
- Run:
  `c:\Drop\soaptest>Program.exe` 
   `Conversion rate from USD to EUR is 0.7221`

Comment: Too hard... Can you give a simple code example, how to create a request to server and how to read server's response?

Comment: You are asking how to communicate with one of the most complicated standards in existence... it is not an easy one-liner.  The introduction linked is quite complete in how to communicate with the server.