# Testing Web Service in SoapUi

Tags: web-services, soap, soapui

I been testing few web services in past using SoapUI. All the end points always ended with ?wsdl but this time round the WS end point ends with .svc and I cannot find a way to test it in SoapUI when i create new SOAP project but I can only enter wsdl end point.

How can I test svc is it .NET end point...?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, if your Service ends with ".svc" it's a WCF service.

- This thread might help you to retreive the WSDL associated with your service : [what is WSDL URI in WCF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860408/what-is-wsdl-uri-in-wcf)
- And you may encounter this issue later : https://berendjdejong.wordpress.com/2011/03/18/soapui-and-wcf-service-testing/

Hope those clues might help you.